How to add a new cafe (element) to database(SQLite) using Python Flask?
This is my code:
@app.route("/add", methods=["POST"])
def post_new_cafe():
    new_cafe = Cafe(
        name=request.form.get("name"),
        map_url=request.form.get("map_url"),
        img_url=request.form.get("img_url"),
        location=request.form.get("loc"),
        has_sockets=bool(request.form.get("sockets")),
        has_toilet=bool(request.form.get("toilet")),
        has_wifi=bool(request.form.get("wifi")),
        can_take_calls=bool(request.form.get("calls")),
        seats=request.form.get("seats"),
        coffee_price=request.form.get("coffee_price"),
    )
    db.session.add(new_cafe)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(response={"success": "Successfully added the new cafe."})

The html file used is basically a static page like
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Cafe&Wifi API</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Welcome to the Cafe & Wifi API</h1>
   </body>
</html>

The Error I'm getting when I open the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/add on my browser is
Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

What should I do to get the form to work?

How are you calling it? Provide the full command if you are using curl. Or are you opening it in the browser? Is there HTML code along with this?

Opening it in a browser. I only have index.html that contains                       



Cafe&Wifi API


Welcome to the Cafe & Wifi API

'
Only URLs that correspond to routes which support GET  can be opened in a web browser.

This is likely due to not having defined a GET route for the landing page
from flask import render_template
@app.route('/add')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

Make sure to replace index.html with your html file name and make sure the file is placed under the templates/ directory.
You have only defined @app.route("/add", methods=["POST"]) which is not suitable for a GET request that your browser issues when the webpage is opened.
